# Can I use rdesktop to acces windows from linux on the same computer?

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, linux-mint, remote-access

I have windows 10 and linux mint 17.3 installed on my computer (disk partitioned). I use linux the most, but I need to access some specific programs (fireworks, dreamweaver, spss, for example).

I know the option to use a vmware, but I would like to know if it is possible to just use a remote access from linus to windows, so I can use the programs and files I already have installed on windows but remaining on linux.

Comment: @Moab re-read the question. Op has two partitions on the _same machine_; it's not a simple case of remoting to a different machine.

Comment: "so I can use the programs and files"; you could mount your Windows partitions in the Linux (and vice-versa), although the driver support in both cases is a little flaky. You can't run programs like this though.

Answer (score 1):

In a disk partitioned setup there is no way to do that, simply because Windows cannot run at the same time as GNU/Linux.

Virtual machine is the way to go in my opinion (be it VMware, Virtualbox or some other software).

Comment: Ok, apparently you can boot OS using the hard disk partition, although I haven't tested: VMware https://blogs.vmware.com/vmtn/2007/01/running_a_physi.html , VirtualBox http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html . Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

No, there cannot be such an option. Remote Desktop is a communication protocol between a server (e.g. a machine running Windows) and a client (e.g. a machine running Linux). Since a single computer can only run a single OS at a time, it can be either a client or a server, not both.

Of course, you can run Windows 10 in a VM on Linux, set up a network interface inside the VM and use Remote Desktop to login from Linux to your Windows 10 VM. It's rather pointless though, since you're already running Windows 10 in a VM at that point.